# No API key provided

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I try to connect and create account on stripe side and got error:

> No API key provided. Set your API key when constructing the StripeClient instance, or provide it on a per-request basis using the api_key key in the $opts argument.

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stripe\StripeClient;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class SellerController extends Controller
{
    protected StripeClient $stripeClient;
    protected DatabaseManager $databaseManager;

    public function __construct(StripeClient $stripeClient, DatabaseManager $databaseManager)
    {
        $this->stripeClient = $stripeClient;
        $this->databaseManager = $databaseManager;
    }

    public function showProfile($id){
        $seller = User::find($id);

        if(is_null($seller)){
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('seller', [
            'seller' => $seller,
            'balande' => null
        ]);
    }

    public function redirectToStripe($id){
        $seller = User::find($id);

        if(is_null($seller)){
            abort(404);
        } 
        
        if(!$seller->completed_stripe_onboarding){

            $token = Str::random();
            $this->databaseManager->table('stripe_state_tokens')->insert([
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now(),
                'seller_id' => $seller->id,
                'token' => $token
            ]);

            // account id

            if (is_null($seller->stripe_connect_id)) {
    
                // Create account
                $account = $this->stripeClient->accounts->create([
                    'country' => 'FR',
                    'type'    => 'express',
                    'email'   => $seller->email,
                                   
                ]);

                $seller->update(['stripe_connect_id' => $account->id]);
                $seller->fresh();
            }
            $onboardLink =$this->stripeClient->accountLinks->create([
                'account' => $seller->stripe_connect_id,
                'refresh_url' => route('redirect.stripe', ['id' =>$seller->id]),
                'return_utl' => route('save.stripe', ['token' => $token]),
                'type' => 'acccount_onboarding'
            ]);

            return redirect($onboardLink->url);
        }

        $loginLink = $this->stripeClient->accounts->createloginLink($seller->stripe_connect_id);
        return redirect($loginLink->url);
    }

    public function saveStripeAccount($token){
        $stripeToken = $this->databaseManager->table('stripe_state_tokens')
        ->where('token', '=', $token)
        ->first();

        if(is_null($stripeToken)){
            abort(404);
        }

        $seller = User::find($stripeToken->seller_id);

        $seller->update([
            'completed_stripe_unboarding' => true
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('seller.profile', ['id' => $seller->id]);
    }
}
```

services.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Mailgun, Postmark, AWS and more. This file provides the de facto
    | location for this type of information, allowing packages to have
    | a conventional file to locate the various service credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
        'scheme' => 'https',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],
    'stripe' => [
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],
];
```

appserviceprovider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Carbon;
use Stripe\StripeCLient;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(StripeClient::class, function(){
            return new StripeClient(config('stripe.secret'));
           });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
       $this->app->singleton(StripeClient::class, function(){
        return new StripeClient(config('stripe.secret'));
       });
    }
}
```

How to fix this error ? i suppose i have to inject to modify somethings about StripeClient no?

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppServiceProvider` file, you are missing the config file to look for the stripe details. Instead it needs to look like this:

```php
// Option 1:
return new StripeClient(config('services.stripe.secret'));

// Option 2:
return new StripeClient(['api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret')]);
```

You can test the return value of `config` by using the `dd` function (before the `return` statement), e.g.:

```php
dd(config('services.stripe.secret'));
```

EDIT:
You only need the singleton definition in the AppServiceProvider `register` function, not in the `boot` function.

Finally, you may need to get out of Stripe sandbox mode by using the `sk_test_xxxxxxx` api key before you can use the `sk_live_xxxxxxx` api key.

Comment: i did what you've tell me but I still have the same error and the command dd didnt even work

Comment: 2 questions:

1) Have you got an `.env` file in the root directory of your project and does it contain values for `STRIPE_KEY` and `STRIPE_SECRET`? ***DO NOT POST THE CONTENTS OF IT HERE!***

2) What do you mean by `dd` didn't work, as in PHP complained it didn't exist or the result of it was empty?

Comment: yes my .env contain STRIPE_KEY and STRIPE_SECRET with the keys from stripe. I put dd after return new StripeClient(config(services....) and the dd function do nothing,  i got back on the no api key provided page

Comment: Ah, okay. the `dd` command would need to come _before_ the `return` statement. Also, does your secret start with `sk_live` or `sk_test`?

Comment: If it begins with `whsec_` then that is for verifying a payload from Stripe and you should try `config('services.stripe.key')`

Comment: no its only STRIPE_KEY="pk_test_xxxxxxx" STRIPE_SECRET="sk_test_xxxxxxx"

Comment: The value should start with `sk_xxxx` so `services.stripe.secret` should be correct. I'd also recommend what @Asif suggested to clear any caches.

Comment: Re-reading the error message, I'd suggest using the following: `return new StripeClient(['api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret')]);` (and verifying that `config('services.stripe.secret')` contains the value you expect it to).

Comment: Ok so I did change the key with "pk_xxxx" and "sk_xxxx" and after I cache:clear and config:clear too. And change with `return new StripeClient(['api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret')]);` but its still tell to provide an API Key

Comment: Have you managed to confirm that you are getting the expected value from `config('services.stripe.secret')`?

Comment: ' 'stripe' => [
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],' its a part of my services.php in the config file

Comment: Also, you only need the singleton definition in the AppServiceProvider `register` function, not the `boot` function as well.

Comment: I only keep the register function but its still maintain the error I've no idea what problem can it be

Comment: Okay, Stripe may require you to use your `sk_test_xxxx` api key first before they let you use the live key. Also, in the boot function of your AppServiceProvider can you put the `dd(config('services.stripe.secret'));` before you register your singleton to check whether there is a value?

Comment: Okay so i did what you've tell me and with the dd function i got the value sk_test_xxxxx so what's next?

Comment: Excellent, remove the `dd` statement and make sure that same `config` call is happening inside your singleton definition. Finally, if that is still returning the same error message from Stripe verify that your API key is correct in Stripe itself. If all else fails you might need to raise a ticket with Stripe.

Comment: Ok so i did it and the error is still happening i dont why Im going to raise a ticket with Stripe. Thank for the time Peter I appreciate, have a nice day bye. I let a comment in the futur if have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Stripe API key is set in your .env file

```
STRIPE_KEY=your_stripe_api_key
STRIPE_SECRET=your_stripe_api_secret
```

Also clear your config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If you're using a caching mechanism, such as OPcache or APC, make sure to clear the cache after updating the configuration files.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Yes my Stripe Api Key are set in .env and I've try what you've tell me, still get the same error